# Can corda nodes part of multiple corda network ? One corda node with multiple NMS possible ? How to implement private NMS?

Tags: corda

1. Can corda nodes part of multiple corda networks ? Currently nodes are part of network using single NMS/Doorman service. Is it possible single corda node register multiple doorman service ? If no then is corda node support multiple corda networks?
2. How to implement private NMS which is part of Main NMS ?

Comment: Hey Vishal, take a look here https://solutions.corda.net/business-networks/what-is-a-business-network.html and here https://corda.network

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not supported as of Corda v.3. But is discussed as a potential future of Corda